# Load many csv files at once in Power BI

Tags: csv, power-query, microsoft-powerbi

I received a relational database export where each csv file represents a table.
Just 107 files, and i need to import them all to Power BI...
Am i out of luck and need to import each of them individually?
Or there's a practical way?

I know there's the "Folder" connector thats used to combine files under the same model.
It's NOT my case since each table has it own's set of columns!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are out of luck. The "Folder" connector assumes every file has the same structure.

An easier and more efficient way would be to connect Power BI to the relational database where you can check off the 107 tables in the Navigation UI to generate 107 Queries and Tables in Power BI. There are many other advantages e.g. speed, datatypes, currency of data...